# Prove that the quotient map $P:G \to G/H$ is a covering space.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Suppose that the subspace topology on $H$ is the discrete topology. Prove that the quotient map $P:G \to G/H$ is a covering space.

My attempt:

For an element $a_1H$ in $G/H$ open nbd $U$ of $a_1H$ in $G/H$ then $p^{-1}(U)$ contains the elements of the type $ah$ now how can I divide it into open disjoint slices? For bijectiveness I think $a_i$ s.t $i \in I$ index set where each $a_i$ generate different $a_iH \in U$ . But why this is open in $G$?

Comment: well this is not exactly my field, so it might be totally nonsense what I say, but the quotient map should be open therefore your set there is also open. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61173/when-quotient-map-is-open

Comment: I have proved that then what to do next?

Comment: possible duplicate of [$G$ topological group, $H$ discrete normal subgroup, $p$ projection, form Covering Space.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511466/g-topological-group-h-discrete-normal-subgroup-p-projection-form-coveri)