# Let $G$ be a Lie Group, $H$ a disconnected closed Lie Subgroup, then $\pi: G/H_0 \to G/H$ is a covering map.

Tags: differential-topology, lie-groups, covering-spaces

Let $G$ be a connected Lie Group and $H$ a disconnected closed Lie Subgroup, defining $H_0$ as the connected component of the neutral element $1$ of $H$ we can define projection map

\begin{align}
\pi:G/H_0&\to G/H\\
g H_0&\to g H.
\end{align}

It is written in the book "Grupos de Lie - San Martin" that above map $\pi$ is a covering map, however, no demonstration is provided.

Does anyone know how to prove such a claim?

It is easy to see that $\pi$ is an open function and $\text{dim}(G/H_0) = \text{dim}(G/H)$. However, I don't know how to argue that this implies $\pi$ be a covering map.

Comment: Can you explain what is $H_0$?  If $G$ is connected, the connected component of $1$ should just be $G$, right?

Comment: $H_0$ is the connected component of $1$ of the Lie subgroup $H$, I edited the post.

Comment: Oh okay.  Can you prove the special case where $\operatorname{Dim} H = 0$ and $H_0 = 1$?  I think the general case is similar to that.

Comment: @D_S Yes. In this case, is easy because $H$ is a discrete lie subgroup.

Comment: Here a proof of the special case https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511466/g-topological-group-h-discrete-normal-subgroup-p-projection-form-coveri